# How can I reorder enumerate task items in two columns?

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem

I can make two columns of numbering list using `\task` like this:

```
1. Choose your colour!
   a. red        b. yellow
   c. brown      d. purple
   e. green
```

But, I want the enumerate looks like this:

```
1. Choose your colour!
   a. red        d. purple
   b. yellow     e. green
   c. brown
```

Any idea to solve this? (That custom enumitem lists is always used in my country.)

Comment: Hi ! Could you share your code ?

Comment: Kurniawan Prihadi, any news?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From one of my textbooks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
\item   Choose your colour!
    \begin{multicols}{2}    
        \begin{enumerate}
    \item   tip storitve
    \item   kakovost storitve
    \item   prenos podatkov
    \item   upravljanje povezave
    \item   pospešena dostava
    \item   poročanje o stanju
    \item   varnost
    \item[]
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. But might I suggest placing `multicols` after the first `enumerate` so the options are all below the `Choose your colour`